# Grid-search-cross-validation in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn

Can grid-search-cross-validation be used to extract best parameters with Decision Tree classifier?
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/model_selection.html

Answer (score 11):

Why not ?

I invite you to check documentation of [GridsearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV).

#### Example

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

param_grid = {'max_depth': np.arange(3, 10)}

tree = GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeClassifier(), param_grid)

tree.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
tree_preds = tree.predict_proba(xtest)[:, 1]
tree_performance = roc_auc_score(ytest, tree_preds)

print 'DecisionTree: Area under the ROC curve = {}'.format(tree_performance)
```

And to extract the best parameters :

```
tree.best_params_
Out[1]: {'max_depth': 5}
```

Comment: Thanks. So, tree.best_params_ are the names of the best features? if my feature names be ['a','b','c','d','e'], how can I know the best feature names?

Comment: `tree.best_params_` returns a dictionnary like `{'params1' : bestparam}`. In that case you would have for instance `{'a' : 1, 'b' : 0.4, ...}`

Comment: If you are using `GridSearchCV`, don't you want to use your full dataset to fit rather than just the training subset?  Since `GridSearchCV` is taking performing some variant of k-fold CV, it seems like a waste of data to only use your training data.

Comment: Never use your test set to find hyperparemeters because you will always end up overfitting by introducing information you should not have in the training phase. CV is mostly used to mimic a test set when you don't have a validation sample.

Comment: @gowithefloww Agree! Hyperparameter tuning using test set would be perfect example of paining target around arrow.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for decision tree Grid Search

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

def dtree_grid_search(X,y,nfolds):
    #create a dictionary of all values we want to test
    param_grid = { 'criterion':['gini','entropy'],'max_depth': np.arange(3, 15)}
    # decision tree model
    dtree_model=DecisionTreeClassifier()
    #use gridsearch to test all values
    dtree_gscv = GridSearchCV(dtree_model, param_grid, cv=nfolds)
    #fit model to data
    dtree_gscv.fit(X, y)
    return dtree_gscv.best_params_
```