# GridSearchCV and the tree classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tree, classification, gridsearchcv

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31161637/grid-search-cross-validation-in-sklearn) it is mentioned

```
  param_grid = {'max_depth': np.arange(3, 10)}
  tree = GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeClassifier(), param_grid)
  tree.fit(xtrain, ytrain)
  tree_preds = tree.predict_proba(xtest)[:, 1]
  tree_performance = roc_auc_score(ytest, tree_preds)
```

Q1: once we perform the above steps and get the best parameters, we need to fit a tree with all data (training + validation) and the learned parameters?

Q2: max_depth is specifically mentioned in the parameters, and it is possible to get it by accessing tree.best_params_, what about other parameters that the grid has found? How is it possible to access those to build a good tree?

Comment: Did the solution work?

Comment: Please see below

Answer (score 0):

Answering your first question, when you create your `GridSearchCV` object you can set parameter `refit` as `True` (the default value is `True`) which returns an estimator using the best found parameters on the whole dataset and it can be accessed by the `best_estimator_` attribute. It behaves like a normal estimator and supports the `.predict` method like any other sklearn estimator does.

Now answering your second question, you can get access to all the parameter of the decision tree model that was using to fit the final estimator using the `best_estimator_` attribute itself, but as I said earlier, there is no need for you to fit a new classifier with the best parameters since `refit=True` will do it for you.

Please follow the sample code below to understand this better:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

X, y = make_classification(random_state=0)
param_grid = {'max_depth': np.arange(3, 10), 'min_samples_leaf':np.arange(2,10)}
tree = GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeClassifier(), param_grid)
tree.fit(X, y)
GridSearchCV(cv=None, error_score=nan,
             estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(ccp_alpha=0.0, class_weight=None,
                                              criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
                                              max_features=None,
                                              max_leaf_nodes=None,
                                              min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
                                              min_impurity_split=None,
                                              min_samples_leaf=1,
                                              min_samples_split=2,
                                              min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
                                              presort='deprecated',
                                              random_state=None,
                                              splitter='best'),
             iid='deprecated', n_jobs=None,
             param_grid={'max_depth': array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]),
                         'min_samples_leaf': array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])},
             pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', refit=True, return_train_score=False,
             scoring=None, verbose=0)

# This is how your best estimator looks like
print(tree.best_estimator_)
DecisionTreeClassifier(ccp_alpha=0.0, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
                       max_depth=3, max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
                       min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                       min_samples_leaf=6, min_samples_split=2,
                       min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort='deprecated',
                       random_state=None, splitter='best')

# you can directly use it for prediction as shown below
tree.best_estimator_.predict(X) 
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
       0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```

Comment: Thanks. In your example, you just used X. What if you had used X_train and X_valid? My question is if you only train using X_train, should you go back and train with the grid search best parameters and X again?

Comment: Unfortunately, the above code throws error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ccp_alpha'.  I updated my anaconda few days ago, so I am not sure what is the issue